# How to move image on finger touch in android?

Tags: android

I need to move the position of the image with the direction of finger in the easiest way possible.I found out the direction of the finger touch but I don't know how to move the image in the direction of finger.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial will be helpful to you:

http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-5-implementing-the-drag-gesture/1789?tag=content;siu-container

Comment: That tutorial walks you through exactly what you asked for.

Comment: What if I want to restrict the movement of image.I am able to move the image but could not restrict it.I only want to move image upside and down.